# Expressing the order o f a planar graph with two properties.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a plane graph of order $n$ and size $m$ for which the boundary of every interior region of $G$ is a triangle, and the boundary of the exterior region is a $k$-cycle, ($k>2$). What is $m$ in terms of $n$ and $k$?

Use Euler's identity to get things started, $n-m+r=2$, $\; r$ is the number of regions. So we can find how many triangles there will be in the graph. I'm a little stuck because I don't know how I can use $k$ here. If I could somehow find the number of bridges I might be getting somewhere, but $k$ doesn't tell us that. The graph could be a tree or even a single path. I've done a few random graphs and I can't see a pattern between $m$ and $n$ & $k$. If someone could give me a jump start I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Add up the number of edges bounding each region (in terms of $r$ and $k$), and note that this will be equal to $2m$. Then use Euler's formula to get $r$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I get $2m = 3(r-1) + k$, but doesn't that create problems, the fact that bridges can be counted twice in such a $k$-cycle? This won't necessarily give us twice the number of edges, will it (since some edges were counted twice)?

Comment: @LonelyMathematician Ah, I probably should have read your original post a little more carefully. I think it's safe to assume there are no bridges, since if there were a bridge, the boundary of the outer region would not be a simple cycle (a $k$-cycle generally refers to $C_k$).

Comment: Well I took your advice and tried my resulting function $m = f(n,k)$ on a few graphs and I get the correct answer but, are you sure we can assume there aren't any bridges? I initially thought this, but one of my classmates insisted that we could still have bridges.

Comment: Nope you were right, an edge is a bridge iff it does not lie on a cycle, and we know all edges will either be on a triangle or on the outside cycle of length $k$.